# Select all type of data

Tags: mysql

My table is like:

```
id     name        seller    product
1      bags          s1       gold bag
2      shirt         s1       shirts
3      shows         s1       big show
4      jewellery     s1       jewellery
5      Tv            s2        Tv
```

I want to select 4 rows and in 4 rows must have seller `s1` and `s2` both results. Right now when I selecting 4 records so first 4 record are selecting that have seller `s1`

Edit

---

I have tried "**GROUP BY**" but its only returning single result.... I mean id=1

And
select distinct seller from table
getting only only 2 rows

I need
"**I want to select 4 rows and in 4 rows must have seller `s1` and `s2` both results.**"

Comment: i want to be this first record id- 1 and 2end - id-5 and then others

Comment: what you have code for this ?

Comment: " select distinct seller from table " no not need this i need select 4 rows and in 4 rows must have seller s1 and s2 both results. Right now when I selecting 4 records so first 4 record are selecting that have seller s1

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct seller from table
```

though this will return only 2 rows

Comment: not need this i need to select 4 rows and in 4 rows must have seller s1 and s2 both results. Right now when I selecting 4 records so first 4 record are selecting that have seller s1

Comment: Query as it is does not yield the result requested by PO.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution will return 4 rows which contain both sellers s1 and s2.

**Code Segment 1**

The code segment returns only 3 records for "s1".  This is accomplished by adding the  `where seller = "s1"` and `limit 3` clause to the query.

```
select id, name, seller, product
from mytable
where seller = 's1'
limit 3
```

The `union` clause joins the two code segments together.

**Code Segment 2**

The second code segment performs a subquery similar to what was seen in the first code segment.  The outer query was added to ensure the limit clause only restricted to the subquery and not to the entire result.

```
select *
from (
select id, name, seller, product
from mytable
where seller = 's2'
limit 1) t1
```

Here is the full code with link to [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/435c2/3/0).

```
select id, name, seller, product
from mytable
where seller = 's1'
limit 3
union
select *
from (
select id, name, seller, product
from mytable
where seller = 's2'
limit 1) t1
```

Comment: Hi @Patricia if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.